# Why PHP Session Variables doesn't work?

Tags: php, session-variables

I'm trying to pass the value of a variable from a php file to another with session variables, but it doesn't work. The variable $id_incidencia in the second file never gets the value of the session variable. Thanks!!

**file1.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'connection.php';
global $connect;

$incidencia = $_POST["incidencia"];
$descripcion = $_POST["descripcion"];
$ubicacion = $_POST["ubicacion"];   

$query = "INSERT INTO incidencias(incidencia, descripcion, ubicacion) VALUES('$incidencia','$descripcion','$ubicacion');";

mysqli_query($connect, $query) or die (mysqli_error($connect));

$id_incidencia = mysqli_insert_id($connect);
$_SESSION['id_incidencia'] = $id_incidencia;

mysqli_close($connect);

?>
```

**file2.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'connection.php';
header('Content-type : bitmap; charset=utf-8');
$id_incidencia = $_SESSION['id_incidencia'];

if(isset($_POST["encoded_string"])){
    global $connect;
    $encoded_string = $_POST["encoded_string"];
    $image_name = $_POST["image_name"];
    $decoded_string = base64_decode($encoded_string);
    $path = 'images/'.$image_name;
    $file = fopen($path, 'wb');

    $is_written = fwrite($file, $decoded_string);
    fclose($file);

    if($is_written > 0) {
        $query = "UPDATE incidencias SET imagen='$path' WHERE id='$id_incidencia'";
        mysqli_query($connect, $query) or die (mysqli_error($connect));
        mysqli_close($connect);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: @Andreas Huh? Why would it be the other way?

Comment: Do you check that `$_SESSION['id_incidencia']` has a value in file1 and it is what you expect?

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: I refer to the session variable, not the post variable, $incidencia and $id_incidencia are not the same. I want to send to the file 2 the value of the $id_incidencia obtained with mysqli_insert_id

Comment: @Andreas What? The session variable is set with the line `$_SESSION['id_incidencia'] = $id_incidencia;`...

Comment: Yes I see that now, got confused with $_session and $_post. Will delete my previous comments

Comment: @MarcB yes, I know that, but I'm trying to fix this first xD

Comment: @JonStirling I have not checked in file1 the value of $_SESSION['id_incidencia'] but I have checked $id_incidencia and is correct